# jquery attribute select on click not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem with the following:

```
$(document).on("click", ".adm_vid_stcs_refresh_btn['data-ctg-id']", function(){
   Categories.ctgId = $(this).attr("data-ctg-id");  
   Categories.ctgType = $(this).attr("data-ctg-type");
   Categories.Ajax();
});
```

When a click the button with class `.adm_vid_stcs_refresh_btn` I get the the following error:

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognised expression: ['data-ctg-id']

How can I select a class with attribute I jquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are using an [attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/) like the [has attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/) you have used, the attribute name should not not be enclosed like a string literal in `''` or `""`

```
 ".adm_vid_stcs_refresh_btn[data-ctg-id]"
```

So

```
$(document).on("click", ".adm_vid_stcs_refresh_btn[data-ctg-id]", function () {
    Categories.ctgId = $(this).attr("data-ctg-id");
    Categories.ctgType = $(this).attr("data-ctg-type");
    Categories.Ajax();
});
```